# How to bind with LDAPS to Azure AD Domain Services

Tags: ldap, azure-active-directory

I'm getting started with Azure AD Domain Services for a new company.

For some applications we need LDAPS access so I was able to set that up and I can connect to the instance from on-premise using ldp.exe.

However I cannot find out how to bind so that I'm authenticated. I tried the e-mailadress and password of an admin user and other various syntaxes but none seem to work.

Is there any guidance on this?

Comment: Did you referred this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-configure-secure-ldap

Comment: Yes, I have LDAPS set up, I can connect to it, but I don't know what parameters to use for binding. I keep getting Unauthorized / wrong credentials errors.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I know of two bind DNs that work for me in Azure AD Domain Services:

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=<Full> <Name>,ou=AADDC Users,dc=<domain>,dc=<tld>" -W -H ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX
```

or

```
ldapsearch -D "<samaccountname>@<domain>.<tld>" -W -H ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX
```